# Скрыть строки по условию в Excel

Tags: excel

В файле excel в строках **A5**:**F222** имеется перечень работ с их описанием, в колонке **G** напротив каждой из работ краткое название работы (демонтаж, монтаж, ревизия и тд.). В строке **A3** выпадающий список этих кратких наименований работ, как скрывать всё лишнее оставляя только то, что выбрал в списке **А3**.
К примеру выбрал из списка **A3** "монтаж" и строки от **А5** до **F222** не имеющие в колонке **G** это слово (монтаж) скрывались. Чтобы автоматический фильтр выполнялся именно от 5 до 222 строки, т.к. и выше и ниже этих строк есть иная информация.

Comment: Дайте пример таблицы. Чем вас обычный автофильтр не устраивает?

Comment: Автофильтр это что то громоздкое и сложное. Можно же как то средствами vba сделать. https://my-files.ru/9trq8q - это пример